# Something like float:top?

Tags: html, css

I have this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5bpwckot/

As you can see, if a div is larger than the other, the other gets down.
I'd like to keep the two divs in place, regardless of the top div..

I was wondering if I could do something like `float:top;`

Thanks :)

Here is the code:

***HTML:***

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">Last posted threads</div>
    <div id="halfbloc"> <a href="<?php echo $host ?>/forum/thread1">Thread</a>
        </br>by Username, 1 hour ago.</div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <div id="halftitle" style="float:left;">Last users registered</div>
    <div id="halfbloc">

    <img style="float: left; height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right:3px;" src="img/default.png"><a href="<?php echo $host ?>/profile/3/User3">User3</a>
        </br>3 hours ago
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <img style="float: left; height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right:3px;" src="img/default.png"><a href="<?php echo $host ?>/profile/2/User2">User2</a>
        </br>3 hours ago
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <img style="float: left; height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right:3px;" src="img/default.png"><a href="<?php echo $host ?>/profile/1/User1">User1</a>
        </br>4 hours ago
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#halftitle {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to top, #0e75ba, #021c55);
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width:241px;
    position:relative;
}
#halfbloc {
    background-color: #f7fafb;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width:241px;
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
}

/*ignore this*/
.sep {
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just include `vertical-align:top;` to get this fixed

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bpwckot/1/)